# extract middle of string with pure bash

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have... 
string='first/second/third'

how can I extract 'second' from string using pure bash only (not awk/sed etc.) and in 1 line?

I know I can do ${string#*/} to get 'second/third' but what about just 'second'

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/env bash

STRING="first/second/third"

TEXT=$STRING
TEXT=${TEXT#*/}
TEXT=${TEXT%/*}

echo $TEXT
```

Bash also supports `regex`. Which can be useful here, as well as other places with more complex needs. For your use case, you can easily match each portion, and extract it.

```
#!/bin/env bash

STRING="first/second/third"

[[ $STRING =~ ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ]] && echo matched

echo [1] ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo [2] ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
echo [3] ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

Comment: By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
                variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: ... I would also put the *ERE* inside a variable, just as a best practice which is likely to save some time fixing failed character-escaping attempts in the future :-)

Answer (score 3):

One option:

```
second="$string" ; second="${second#*/}" ; second="${second%/*}"
# now "$second" is 'second'
```

Another option:

```
IFS=/ read -r first second third <<< "$string"
# now "$first" is 'first', "$second" is 'second', and "$third" is 'third'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `IFS` and `read`:

```
 string='first/second/third'
 IFS='/' read -r a b c <<< "${string}" && echo ${b}
```

prints "second".

Answer (score 2):

Using bash array:

```
string='first/second/third'
```

You can do:

```
IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< "$string" && echo "${arr[1]}"
```

Or using `IFS` based splitting:

```
(IFS=/ arr=($string) && echo "${arr[1]}")
```

Both commands will print:

```
second
```

Comment: This sets `IFS` for the current shell session, not just for the array assignment.

Comment: I would `IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< 'first/second/third'; printf '%s\n' "${arr[1]}"` instead, since failing to double-quote an expansion in this context ( `arr=($string)` ) is a bad practice.